# Measures agreeing on a $\sigma$-field generated by some class of sets

Tags: measure-theory

A $\pi$-class is a nonempty class of subsets of the whole space $X$ that is closed under intersection. I am considering the following proposition:

**Proposition 1:** Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a nonempty class of subsets of $X$ and let $\mathcal{F}$ be the $\sigma$-field generated by $\mathcal{E}$. Let $\mu$ be a measure on $\mathcal{F}$ which is $\sigma$-finite on $\mathcal{E}$. If $\mu_1$ is another measure on $\mathcal{F}$ such that it agrees with $\mu$ on any $E \in \mathcal{E}$ (i.e. $\mu_1(E) = \mu(E)$ for all $E \in \mathcal{E}$), then they agree on all of $\mathcal{F}$.

I'm thinking about conditions on $\mathcal{E}$. I know this result to be false in general. I also know it is false in general even when we require $\mathcal{E}$ to be a $\pi$-class. **However** I think it is true if we not only require $\mathcal{E}$ to be a $\pi$-class, but also to contain $X$. I haven't worked out all the details, but I think the following proof sketch is valid:

1. Fix a set $A \in \mathcal{E}$ such that $\mu(A)<\infty$. Define
   the class $\mathcal{D} = \{E \in \mathcal{F}: \mu_1(A \cap E) =
       \mu(A \cap E)\}$. Since $\mathcal{E}$ is a $\pi$-class, then
   $\mathcal{D} \supset \mathcal{E}$. Furthermore, $\mathcal{D}$ is a
   $\lambda$-class. Therefore by the $\pi-\lambda$ theorem, $\mathcal{D} \supset \mathcal{F}$.
2. Since $\mathcal{E}$ contains $X$, then any set in $\mathcal{F}$
   can be covered by a countable union of sets of finite measure in
   $\mathcal{E}$ (since $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite on $\mathcal{E}$). Therefore $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite on $\mathcal{F}$.
3. For any set $E \in \mathcal{F}$, we can write $E =
       \cup_1^{\infty} (E \cap E_n)$ for $E_n \in \mathcal{E}$. Then using
   (1) and the fact that we can rewrite this union as a disjoint union,
   we can easily show that $\mu(E) = \mu_1(E)$.

**Question:** First of all, does this proof look legit? Second of all, this seems to me to be the weakest set of assumptions (nonempty, closed under intersections, contains $X$) we can put on $\mathcal{E}$ for **Proposition 1** to hold. Does this seem to be true?

I know that this result holds for finite measures when $\mathcal{E}$ is a $\pi$-class not necessarily containing $X$. I also know that this result holds when $\mathcal{F}$ is only a $\sigma$-*ring* generated by $\mathcal{E}$. I just thought it would be curious if we could show that the result extends to $\sigma$-fields just by throwing $X$ into $\mathcal{E}$.

Comment: I think this hinges on the precise definition of "$\sigma$-finite on $\mathcal{E}$." To avoid any possible confusion, could you state it?

Comment: Ah, yes. By $\sigma$-finite on $\mathcal{E}$ I mean: for any set $E \in \mathcal{E}$, there exists a sequence $\{E_n\}$ of sets in $\mathcal{E}$ with $E \subset \cup_1^{\infty} E_n$ and $\mu(E_n) < \infty$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This argument looks good to me.

It's worth noting that it could take some effort to verify that a measure is $\sigma$-finite on $\mathcal{E}$.  For example, it isn't sufficient that it be a $\sigma$-finite measure (i.e. $\sigma$-finite on $\mathcal{F}$).  Consider for instance $\mathcal{F}$ the Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}$, $\mu$ Lebesgue measure, and $\mathcal{E} = \{(-\infty, a) : a \in \mathcal{R}\}$.

Comment: Gotcha. That's certainly an interesting point. Thanks!